# First Data E4 Gateway Hosted Payment Pages Form Values Missing

Tags: asp.net, forms, missing-data

I'm using the First Data E4 Gateway Hosted Payment Pages.

Under Payment Pages - Receipt Page Settings I've selected: "Automatic linking to the receipt page including result parameters using HTTP POST method (AUTO-POST)". I'm not use Relay Response right now.

Environment: C#, Sql Server, ASP.NET 4.0, Sql Server 2008 R2.

I've successfully sent payment transaction form values to the E4 servers and most of the time I receive the receipt transaction values back to my receipt page.

However, sometimes the form values are not available. This is a problem because with no form values I can't update our database with the results of the credit card transaction and then I can't display our confirmation page because well we don't know if the transaction was successful or not.

I've spoken with First Data E4 technical support and they tell me: 1) They've never heard of a customer not getting the transaction form values, 2) they simply POST the data but don't check if the customer's server actually received the data, 3) they have no error logs so they are not able to tell me if there was a problem on our servers.

I've enabled Failed Request Tracing but have not seen any failures.

I've tried to capture the form values at various points in the page life cycle:

1) Page_Load
2) Page_Init
3) Page_PreInit
4) Render

Again I sometimes get the form values and sometimes I don't regardless of what stage I try to grab the values. My guess at this point is that our server is slow to respond to the request for the receipt page and E4 servers probably give up and thus we don't get the form values.

I just added capture of Request.ContentLength to our transaction logs. I'm wondering in the cases where we don't get any form values maybe we'll get a count in ContentLength and perhaps that will give us a clue as to the problem. I've not received sufficient transaction yet to see where we got a non-zero ContentLength and no form values.

The First Data tech suggested switching to Relay Response to ensure that we eventually get the transaction information so we can update our database. Even if we switch to relay response there's still going to be some cases where we don't get the data on the first POST attempt from E4 servers which means we can't redirect the user to our custom subscription confirmation page.

Here's the code for our receipt page. I just grab the form values, log them, parse the values, and call Process() to update our databases.

```
public partial class GC2_CreditCardFirstDataE4Receipt : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void ReceiveFormData()
    {
        GC2_BLL_CreditCardFirstDataE4Response ResponseObj = new GC2_BLL_CreditCardFirstDataE4Response(Page);
        bool Status;

        this.EnableViewState = false;

        Status = ResponseObj.Log(Page.Request.Form, Page.Request.ContentLength);
        if (!Status)
        {
            Response.Redirect("GC2_HomePage3.aspx");
        }

        Status = ResponseObj.Parse(Page.Request.Form);
        if (!Status)
        {
            Response.Redirect("GC2_HomePage3.aspx");
        }

        ResponseObj.Process(Page.Request.Form, Request.ContentLength);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {

        }
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter WriterObj)
    {
        ReceiveFormData();
        base.Render(WriterObj);
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Ed